# How do I test a webpage with ajax injection using symfony sfTestFunctional?

Tags: symfony-1.4, functional-testing

I have a webpage (pageA) with a hyperlink (linkA), which when clicked, makes an ajax call to retrieve some html (pageB) and dynamically adds a link (linkB) to pageA.  I want my functional test to click on linkA, and then click on linkB when it is created.

The problem I'm having is that when I get sfBrowser to click linkA, the response object only contains pageB and I don't know how to then tell sfBrowser to click linkB.

```
$browser = new sfTestFunctional(new sfBrowser());
$browser->
  get('pageA')->
  with('response')->begin()->
    click('linkA')->
  end()->

  with('response')->begin()->
    click('linkB')->   // I want to do this but I can't because the response is only pageB.
  end();
```

Is there some way to "get back out" to pageA?

Comment: But response from linkA contains linkBn right? Why don't you parse the response from linkA (in fact pageB) to get linkB?

Comment: You cannot test javascript with sfBrowser. Use [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) for this.

Comment: Response from linkA does not contain linkB.  The javascript attached to linkA creates linkB on pageA.

Comment: Oops it's actually the sfTestFunctional class.  Updated question.